# Selenium - Java: Is there any a way to get locator using WebElement instead of By class

Tags: java, selenium

Here is my `fluentWait` method which is working fine. The method consists of a couple of parameters which I have to provide whenever I call this method.

```
public static WebElement fluentWait(final WebDriver driver, final By locator) {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(600))
            .withMessage("Timeout occured!")
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    return wait.until((WebDriver webDriver) -> driver.findElement(locator));

}

fluentWait(driver, By.id ("element"));
```

I am using page object model and I have to hardcode the locator, which is not a best practice at all. Is there any way, so I can call it using something like `fluentWait(driver, PageObject.element);`?

Answer (score -1):

You could use cssSelector

```
fluentWait(driver, By.cssSelector("element"));
```

Comment: I know about it. As I mentioned above, I am using PageObject model. And I would like something
 fluentWait(driver, PageObject.element);

Comment: I need to figure out this line of code in method. so I can pass WebElement from page object. 
return wait.until((WebDriver webDriver) -> driver.findElement(locator));